# How to properly handle this context to associate certificates with registration types?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page with a form for a user associate certificates with registration types of a conference.

The user needs to select a registration type in a radio button, write the content in the textarea input and then click "Save".

The code below is working but there is an issue. Any time a user click in a registration type, writes some content in the text area and click "Save" in the registration_types tabe the column "certificate_id" is updated with the created certificate id, this is correct. But the issue is that is always created a new certificate record in the database and that doesnt seem correct because the user is only associating and updating a certificate with a registration type.

Do you know how to properly handle this context?

```
<form id="edit_registration_types" method="post"
      action="{{route('certificates.store', ['conference_id' => $conference->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label>Certificate</label>
                @foreach($registrationType as $rtype)
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input
                                {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $rtype->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}
                                class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton"
                                value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            Certificate for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
                        </label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Configure the certificate for the selected registration type</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="certificate_content" id="" rows="3">{{ old('certificate_content') }}</textarea>
    </div>
        <button class="btn-outline-primary btn">Save equal for all registration types</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

CertificatesController:

```
class CertificateController extends Controller
{
    public function create($id){

        $conference = Conference::find($id);
        $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conference_id', $id)->get();
        return view('certificates.index')->with('conference', $conference)->with('registrationType', $registrationType);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
           'certificate_content' => 'required'
        ]);

        $certificate = Certificate::create([
            'content' => $request->certificate_content,
        ]);

        $registrationTypeToUpdate = RegistrationType::find($request->radiobutton);
        $registrationTypeToUpdate->certificate_id = $certificate->id;
        $registrationTypeToUpdate->save();

        Session::flash('success','Certificate updated');

        return redirect()->back();

    }
}
```

Comment: you need a certificate id in form hidden field or in your post request url and using that certificate id fetch the certificate and update it

Comment: Thanks, but for example if there are no certificates stored in db yet and the user click in a registration type (radio button)  and enters some content in the textarea it should be created an entry in the certificates table with the id and content and also the registration type "certificate_id" should be updated. Then what is necessary is to show on the certificates page when the radio button of a specific registration type is selected show in the textarea the stored content of the certificate of that registration type and in that textarea input have the id of the certificate?

Comment: then you need to set the certificate_id in hidden filed if user just updating it and when user post then post the certificate_id and find certificate with this id. if record found then no need to create record just update its content and use that id in registration type

Comment: Thanks, but Im not understanding how to differentiate if the user is updating or not. Because there is no page to create a certificate, the page only have radio buttons (each radio button corresponds to an existing registration type) and the user can only select a radio button that corresponds to a registration type and introduce some content and click in "Save" button.